# Regex java - check either space or character

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to write a regex for occurrence of either multiple spaces or characters within the tag. I wrote regex like this-

```
[tag:title](.*?)[tag:/title].
```

But in the string if there are multiple spaces after  it doesn't match it. If there is a single space or character it matches it. 
I also tried

```
<title>([\\s.]*?)</title>
```

but it doesn't work.
Please help me to correct my regex.

My program is -

```
        public static void main(String[] args) {
        String source1;
        source1="<tag>               apple</tag>          <b>hello</b>      <tag>       orange  gsdggg  </tag>  <tag>p wfwfw   ear</tag>";

        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(getTagValues(source).toArray())); 
}


private static List<String> getTagValues(String str) {

        if (str.toString().indexOf("&amp;") != -1) 
          {   
            str = str.toString().replaceAll("&amp;", "&");// replace &amp; by &
            //  System.out.println("removed &amp formatted--" + source);
          } 


        final Pattern TAG_REGEX = Pattern.compile("<title>(.*?)</title>");
        final List<String> tagValues = new ArrayList<String>();
        final Matcher matcher = TAG_REGEX.matcher(str);
        int count=0;
        while (matcher.find()) {
            tagValues.add(matcher.group(1));
            count++;
        }
        System.out.println("Total occurance is -" + count);
        return tagValues;
```

}

Comment: Do you mind posting a sample of the text you are processing?

Comment: Basically, you want everything within the `<title></title>` tag, huh?

Comment: You can use `(\\s|.)*`

Comment: If you want to match everything within `<title>` tag, you can use this: `<title>(.*)<\/title>`

Comment: @Machina I have added my code.

Comment: @hend and  Zereges I tried but it didn't work. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to check for multiple spaces your must you use:

```
\\s+
```

So your pattern will become:

```
([\\s+.]*/)]
```

Or you could use something like:

```
(\\s|.)*
```

Read about Regex [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html).

You can read a tutorial on String Patterns [here](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JavaRegularExpressions/article.html).